One's nerves could not stand it
Does this make sense implying that he can't take it anymore?
His nerves could not stand it and then he hit the wall with his hand.

Yes, basically. Speaking of "my nerves" to mean "my mental condition" is a bit nineteenth-century; it's a bit of a running joke in Pride and Prejudice ("My poor nerves!"); see https://www.sciencemuseum.org.uk/objects-and-stories/medicine/nerves-neuroses. But we still use it in phrases like "it gets on my nerves."

@AndyBonner - even in 1950s and 60s London, my mother had relatives and acquaintances who 'suffered with their nerves', and sometimes people had mysterious things called 'nervous breakdowns'.

It's not idiomatic to say His nerves can't stand it. Either It gets on his nerves or He can't stand it. The other usage I still often here is My nerves are shot.

@FumbleFingers - His nerves can't stand it - you do see it from time to time, especially in the past tense (couldn't).

@MichaelHarvey: Its heyday was back in the late 1800s, but according to that chart it's suddenly had a huge revival in the last couple of decades. Sounds affected and literary to me - I wouldn't advise learners to think of it as "normal English".

@FumbleFingers I clicked through to the results for 2010-2019 and found a lot of recently-published books containing older texts. Personal Diaries from the Great War, Anthology of Colonial Australian Adventure Fiction, etc.

Please provide more details and context. Are you suggesting that he suddenly snapped and punched something? "His nerves couldn't take it" suggests something more gradual to me: not sudden rage but increased fear and anxiety. In expressions like "my nerves are shot", "his nerves were worn down by years of suffering", "steady your nerves", etc, the meaning of nerves is more like "worry or anxiety" than "boldness, fortitude".
